# Se pierde la sesión cuando cambio de pantalla Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Estoy haciendo una APP, y estoy creando mis variables de sesión para identificar al usuario, todo funciona perfecto hasta que cambio de vista.
En mi controlador de login ya puse

```
$this->session->set_userdata('id', $obj[0]->ID);
header('Location: midominio.com/landing')
```

No tengo ningun problema, de hecho si hago

```
echo $this->session->userdata('id');
```

me trae la información que acabo de meter.
El problema es cuando hago el redirect a otro controlador que llamé Landing donde tengo esto

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Landing extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index(){
    $this->load->view('landing');
    }
}
```

Ya tengo cargada en autoload la librería de sesión

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Cuando intento cargar la vista `landing` existe esta validación para saber si está logueado el usuario

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  if( !$this->session->has_userdata('id') ){
    header('Location: midominio.com');
  }
  else{
?>
<html></html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Siempre me saca, como si no hubiera nada, de hecho si imprimo la variable de sesión de CI me trae esto

```
object(CI_Session)#16 (4) {
  ["userdata"]=>
  &array(1) {
    ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=>
    int(1537469720)
  }
  ["_driver":protected]=>
  string(5) "files"
  ["_config":protected]=>
  &array(9) {
    ["cookie_lifetime"]=>
    int(7200)
    ["cookie_name"]=>
    string(10) "ci_session"
    ["cookie_path"]=>
    string(1) "/"
    ["cookie_domain"]=>
    string(29) "midominio.com"
    ["cookie_secure"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["expiration"]=>
    int(7200)
    ["match_ip"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["save_path"]=>
    string(34) "/opt/alt/php70/var/lib/php/session"
    ["_sid_regexp"]=>
    string(12) "[0-9a-v]{32}"
  }
  ["_sid_regexp":protected]=>
  string(12) "[0-9a-v]{32}"
}
```

En el índice userdata no tengo lo que previamente cargué.
¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Uso PHP 7 / CI 3.x

Comment: ¿Cuales son tus parametros de sessiones (variables)?

Comment: Solo es 1 por el momento, el ID del usuario que se está logueando.

Comment: son diferentes subdominios? /landing es un controlador? probaste con redirect() del helper url?, es linux o windows?

Comment: es el mismo subdominio: subdominio.mipagina.com
ya usé redirect, usé $_SESSION, he intentado con cookies, y todo se pierde cuando cambio de URL, es Linux

Answer (score -1):

Yo lo utilizo de esta manera y me funciona perfecto

```
login controller

$data = array(
    'is_logued_in'      =>  TRUE,
    'idusuario'         =>  $check_user->idusuario,
    'nombre'            =>  $check_user->nombre,
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
redirect(base_url().'dashboard',$data);
```

---

```
dashboard controller

function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logued_in') == true)
        {
            $idusuario = $this->session->userdata('idusuario');

            $this->load->view('dashboard/index_view');

        }else{

            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_usuario','Usted no se encuentra logeado');
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

Comment: No me funciona, la variable de sesión sigue sin existir en la validación.

Comment: ¿Y que es lo que estas haciendo?

Comment: Copié lo mismo que me pasaste, la misma estructura, pero sigue sin settear la sesión, la borra cuando redirecciono. Y cuando llega al otro controlador ya no está ninguno de los índices de la sesión

Comment: Que raro, ¿Que navegador usas?

Comment: Chome, pero bueno es una app multi.plataforma, debería funcionar en todos lados. Además la sesión está en el back no en el front

Comment: Bien extraño.. Con ese codigo que te puse siempre me ha funcionado sin poblemas.

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201191/codeigniter-no-carga-session-al-recargar