# CodeIgniter no carga session al recargar

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Trabajo en una aplicación con CodeIgniter y tengo el problema de que al recarga la pagina o llamar otro controlador pierdo los valores de la variables de session.

La creo así:

```
    $nuevoUsuario = array(
            'usuario' => $this->input->post('usuario'),
            'contrasena' => $this->input->post('contrasena')
        );
        // almacenar en sesion el usuario y la contraseña
        $this->session->set_userdata($nuevoUsuario);
```

En la primera re-dirección se me cargan los datos bien. los muestro con:

```
 <?php print_r($this->session->userdata()) ?>
```

Y obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, el problema es como ya comente, cuando recargo o llamo a otro controlador que pierdo esos datos obteniendo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve pierdo los datos y se me cambia la **ci_last_regenerate.**

Mi configuración de CodeIgniter es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi configuración de php en relación a la sesiones es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve pongo el:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'PHPSESSID';
```

Igual que el de la configuración devuelta por phpinfo() y aun así no funciona.
La cosa es que en local funciona perfectamente.

He mirado documentación y probado mil formas que veo por Internet y no encuentro soluciones. ¿Alguien le ha pasado?

Un saludo.

Comment: Y en qué momento mandas a llamar el primer recuadro de código donde defines el userdata, osease en el login o como es que manejas tus sesiones.

Answer (score 0):

Debes darle un nombre al la cookie de sesión:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'NOMBRE DE COOKIE DE SESION';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 'Tiempo de expiracion de la sesión';
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Hola lo he probado y sigue sin funcionar. He editado un poco la pregunta. No había comentado que en local funciona perfectamente. Es a subir a un servidor externo cuando no funciona.

Comment: Verificaste las versiones de PHP de tu server local y del remoto? aunque no supondría un problema no esta demás la verificación

Answer (score 0):

Se que esta respuesta es tarde, a mi se sucedió algo similar. Buscando una solución me encontré que el problema esta en la fecha, me explico mejor...
Cuando se crea la sesión   $this->session->set_userdata($nuevoUsuario) se crea con la fecha del cliente y a la hora de crear el archivo en el servidor se crea con otra que resulta ser menor, el problema esta en la diferencia de hora entre el cliente y el servidor. Por defecto  la sesión expira en $config['sess_expiration']= 7200 y si le damos un tiempo mayor se soluciona el problema. Esto ultimo no es recomendable, lo mejor es agregar igual zona horaria para los usuarios de la red o analizar la fecha antes de agregar los datos de la sesión. Utilice date_default_timezone_set("UTC") para establecer una zona en el servidor.